# how to use json service for android in wp7

Tags: json, web-services, windows-phone-7

I have create json web service  for Iphone and android now I want to use it in my windows phone 7 application.But i don't no how to use it.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Register(string emailID, string pwd, string name,bool sex)
{
    client_profile _client = new client_profile();

    _client.Email = emailID;
    _client.Password = pwd;
    _client.Gender = sex;
    _client.Firstname = name;
  retutn _client.Insert();
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use service in wp7 and pass value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835601/how-to-use-service-in-wp7-and-pass-value)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few blog posts that describe this, try ["WP7: How to consume JSON data on a Windows Phone 7 application"](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/11/wp7-how-to-consume-json-data-from.html). In brief, fetch your data using a `WebClient`, create a model object and annotate it with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`, then de-serialize as follows:

```
//load into memory stream
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
{
    //parse into jsonser
    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyPersonClass[]));
    MyPersonClass[] obj = (MyPersonClass[])ser.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Comment: i don't no how pass string emailID, string pwd, string name,bool sex values and how to use or access this web service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835601/how-to-use-service-in-wp7-and-pass-value

Comment: @DerekBeattie ... Thanks, it is really annoying when people do this. Makes answering their questions a waste of time. Vote to close.